# ¿Cómo puedo transformar un <script> a un archivo .js?

Tags: javascript

tengo esta etiqueta de Google que debo poner en la cabecera, pero en vez de ello me gustaría llamar un archivo .js (fichero) que tenga dicho script

Esto es lo que pondría en la cabecera:

```
<script src="/js/GoogleTag.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Y lo siguiente no sé cómo escribirlo con lenguaje js dentro del archivo GoogleTag.js

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-11197133132"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-000000000');
</script>
```

Ayuda :(

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que dejar el primer link en tu cabecera y lo que queda en tu archivo "gtag.js"

… tu cabecera quedaría asi:

```
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-11197133132"></script>
  <script src="gtag.js"></script>
```

y el contenido del "gtag.js" sería asi:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-000000000');
```

IMPORTANTE: Recuerda no publicar datos sensibles en tus preguntas.